# как вернуть массив из php в js?

Tags: javascript, php

на сервере возвращаю

```
return json_encode(["allproductInCartCount" => $allproductInCartCount, "total" => $total]);
```

на фронте data 
имеет следующий вид в консоли `{"allproductInCartCount":5,"total":840}`
хочу получить значения `data.allproductInCartCount` а пишет `undefined`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/updateProductInCart/'+id+'/'+value,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.allproductInCartCount)
    }               
});
```

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что он должен вам `JSON` вернуть? Вы парсите его? нет, ну а чему вы удивляетесь? Читаем про `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Если хочу получить именно json-объект, то в аякс-запросе пишу одним из параметров `dataType: 'JSON'`. В этом случае, кажется, распарсивать не приходится.

Comment: почему return json_encode? может всеже echo json_encode....?

Comment: @Quazimorda если не напишите, то jquery все равно сделает это автоматически.

Comment: @teran, а если напишу `dataType: 'text'`? Тут уже всё зависит от того, есть ли в проекте какие-то вручную добавленные настройки ajaxSetup.

Comment: @Quazimorda "если не напишите" значит если вообще не напишите. jquery автоматически пытается определить формат без каких либо настроек. Если при этом ваш бэкенд выдает нужный content-type то вообще проблем нет.

Comment: @teran, чтоб я спорил. Вот только не привык пускать подобные детали на самотёк. ))

Comment: ну так как правильно ? мне нужно получить параметры

Comment: Если строчка "return json_encode(["allproductInCartCount" => $allproductInCartCount, "total" => $total]);" у вас написана в функции, то заменить её на "return ["allproductInCartCount" => $allproductInCartCount, "total" => $total];" а в том месте, где функцию вызываете, написать "echo json_encode(имя_функции);"

Comment: спасибо всем, заработало вот так
return json_encode(["allproductInCartCount" => $allproductInCartCount, "total" => $total]);
и добавил dataType: 'JSON', в ajax
                        
                        });

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/updateProductInCart/'+id+'/'+value,
success: function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data.allproductInCartCount);
}               
});
```

Ну или, как уже догадались, `dataType: JSON` в `ajax`)