# как вернуть правильно массив из php в js?

Tags: javascript, php

на сервере делаю

```
return json_encode(["allproductInCartCount" => $allproductInCartCount, "total" => $total]);
```

на фронте data 
имеет следующий такой вид в консоле {"allproductInCartCount":5,"total":840}

Как получить значения data.allproductInCartCount и data.total ? пишет undefined

```html
$.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '/updateProductInCart/'+id+'/'+value,
                            success: function(data){
              
                                console.log(data.allproductInCartCount)
                            }
                        
                        });
```

Comment: А зачем задавать дважды один вопрос? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093231/как-вернуть-массив-из-php-в-js вам там написали комментариев, ну так и читайте - отвечайте.

Comment: там обсуждение а не ответы

Comment: И в том обсуждении есть подсказка, что на стороне сервера следует использовать не return, а echo.

Comment: так вообще ошибка ничего вообще не возвращает

Comment: спасибо всем, заработало вот так return json_encode(["allproductInCartCount" => $allproductInCartCount, "total" => $total]); и добавил dataType: 'JSON', в ajax });